# XSD Validation Pattern to Enforce LastName/FirstName

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

I need to enforce the pattern LASTNAME/FIRSTNAME Something like Smith/John.

The characters can be Alphanumeric (lowercase/uppercase) also includes special characters like ë  etc.

Pattern:

```
 <xsd:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9]/[a-zA-Z0-9]"/>
```

Basically the rules will be
- Anything before the slash
- Anything after the slash
- Patterns like "/John", "John/" should not be allowed

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ASCII

Assuming that you don't want numbers in the names:

```
        <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z]+/[a-zA-Z]+"/>
```

If you really want to accept numbers in the names:

```
        <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9]+/[a-zA-Z0-9]+"/>
```

Be aware that `0/0`, for example, would be valid in this case, though.

### Unicode

```
        <xs:pattern value="\p{L}+/\p{L}+"/>
```

**Explanation**: `\p{L}` matches a Unicode code point in the Letter category.

Answer (score 1):

Your restriction should be this..

```
<xs:pattern value="(([a-zA-Z0-9])*)([/])(([a-zA-Z0-9])*)"/>
```

I validated this pattern by [XMLSpear](http://www.donkeydevelopment.com/)

Comment: Don't need all those parentheses and probably should change the `*`s to `+`s else "/" would be a valid name.

Comment: @kjhughes I added the parentheses to make clear the expression :) however works fine.

Comment: Thanks kjhughes. You're right. I made the changes as advised, and it works fine.