# XSD Enforce the pattern LASTNAME/FIRSTNAME with special characters allowed as well

Tags: xsd, special-characters

I need to enforce the pattern LASTNAME/FIRSTNAME Something like Smith/John.

The characters can be Alphanumeric (lowercase/uppercase) also includes special characters like ë etc.

Pattern:

```
 <xsd:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9]/[a-zA-Z0-9]"/>
```

Basically the rules will be 
- Anything before the slash 
- Anything after the slash 
- Patterns like "/John", "John/" should not be allowed
- Valid name: "Gçéâêôéâê123/Gçéâêôéâê13" but not "/Gçéâêôéâê123" or "Gçéâêôéâê123/" or "/"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just asked [this same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26176792/290085) and received [an answer that specifically allowed special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26178346/290085).  Why are you repeating your question?

Comment: @kjhughes I tried to edit the question. Actually the need is to allow special characters and Apostrophe as well. However, the below pattern fails for Apostrophe . Any guidance?

Comment: @kjhughes: Names like a's\b's are failing with the pattern as <xsd:pattern value="\w+/\w+"/>. Kindly guide me.

Comment: I recommend expanding upon the [Unicode code point solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26178346/290085) I provided to your previous question.  [Here is a new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26241704/290085) showing what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Unicode Solution

The following regular expression will match your requests, including `"Gçéâêôéâê123/Gçéâêôéâê13"`:

```
<xs:pattern value="[\p{L}\p{P}\p{N}]+/[\p{L}\p{P}\p{N}]+"/>
```

**Explanation**:

- \p{L} matches a letter
- \p{P} matches a punctuation character (to pick up your apostrophe
  request)
- \p{N} matches a number
- `[...]+` matches one or more of its containing characters.
- `/` matches itself

**Potential issue: multiple `/`s:**

Because `\p{P}` matches punctuation characters, including your separator, `/`, you might be better off adding `'` directly rather than as part of the punctuation category:

```
<xs:pattern value="[\p{L}\p{N}']+/[\p{L}\p{N}']+"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the following pattern:

```
 <xsd:pattern value="\w+/\w+"/>
```

and test results until now looks fine.

Comment: This information should be included in your question, not as an "answer".  Thanks.

Comment: @JasonMArcher, no, OP commented on the question and explained that this approach isn't allowing apostrophes as he'd like.  It's clearly only an indication of what OP tried (unsuccessfully) and thus should be an edit of the question as I stated, not an answer.